# Prove that the "even" subset sum problem is NP-complete

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I need to prove that the **even** subset sum problem is NP-complete.

> "Given a ﬁnite set of natural numbers and an even number $n$, decide whether a
>   subset of the given set exists such that the numbers in that subset sum up to $n$.”

I know that in order to do this I first need to prove that it is in NP, and then need to prove that it is also NP-Hard.

I think I can figure out the first part, but I have no idea how I go about proving that it is NP-Hard. Since it is already proven that the normal subset sum problem is NP-complete, it seems logical to reduce from this one:

> “Given a ﬁnite set of natural numbers and a number n, decide whether a subset
>   of the given set exists such that the numbers in that subset sum up to $n$.”

After this, I'm completely stuck. It would be nice if someone could explain the rest of the process to me.

Comment: Your idea of reducing to regular subset-sum is a good one. Usually the way you do this is to pretend that you have a magic machine that can solve instances of subset-sum when $n$ is even, and you  imagine how, if someone gave you an instance where $n$ was odd, you could modify the problem slightly so that $n$ was even, so that you could give the modified problem to your magic machine.

Comment: I tried drawing some diagrams and I believe I have everything clear now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Just to help with searches, the magic machines that @MJD describes above are often called 'oracles' in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reduction I thought of first; there may be others equally simple.

We suppose we have a magic machine $M$ which can solve instances of subset-sum, but only when the target sum is even.  We want to use this to solve all instances of subset-sum.  Suppose the given instance has a set of numbers $N$ and asks us to find a subset $S\subset N$ whose sum is $n$.  If $n$ is even we can hand the problem to the machine and use the solution directly; the only interesting case is what to do when $n$ is odd.  Then let $o$ be some odd number larger than $\sum N$.  We can take $o=1+\sum N$ if that is odd, and otherwise $o = 2+\sum N$.  Clearly we can calculate $o$ in polynomial time.

Then hand the machine $N\cup\{o\}$ and ask it to find a subset that adds up to the target sum $o+n$, which it will do, because $o+n$ is even.  It will give us back a set $S\subset N\cup\{o\}$ such that $\sum S = o+n$.

We can be sure that $o\in S$ because otherwise $S\subset N$ and so $\sum S\le \sum N \lt o \lt o+n$ which we know is not the case.  Then $S\setminus\{o\}$  is the subset we want because it is a subset of $N$, and  $\sum(S\setminus\{o\}) = \sum S - o = n+o-o = n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but there is an alternative

Reduce SUBSET_EVEN_SUM from SUBSET_SUM:

```
SUBSET_SUM(S,t):
input: a set S, a target sum t
output: SUBSET_EVEN_SUM(2*S, 2*t) // multiply each element by 2
```

If `SUBSET_SUM(S,t) == yes`, then the same subset `*2` must sum to `2t`, so `SUBSET_EVEN_SUM(2*S, 2*t) == yes`

If `SUBSET_EVEN_SUM(2*S, 2*t) == yes`, then the same subset `/2` must sum to `t` since each element must be even after our mapping, so `SUBSET_SUM(S,t) == yes`